# DXF files INSERT entity

Tags: java, algorithm, drawing, dxf

I am working on drawing dxf files in Java. So far I am able to draw, `LINES`, `POLYLINES`, `TEXT`, `CIRCLE`, `ARC`, `LWPOLYLINES`.

But I am having problems on drawing `INSERT` entities. I know this is mapped to block entities but when I draw them nothing get displayed. I understand you have to do some transformation on `INSERT` entities but I have no idea how to do that. I Googled a lot about this but no luck. So I hope you can give some direction how to process the `INSERT` entities. I also looked at some frameworks like ycad and dxf-code but that code is difficult to trace.

What is the algortihm for translation `INSERT` to entities like `LINE` and `ARC`

Thanks

Johan

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to provide you a definitive answer because we see no code. But the way `INSERT` features are managed is described on the AutoDesk website. Here is the information for [blocks in DXF files](https://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acadr14/dxf/blocks_in_dxf_files_al_u05_c.htm).

It also provides information about two important entries [`BLOCK`](https://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acadr14/dxf/block_al_u05_c.htm) and [`ENDBLCK`](https://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acadr14/dxf/endblk_al_u05_c.htm).

Here is an example of a block that has a `LINE` and an `ARC` in it. The block will look like this:

[image: Block]

The block is called **SAMPLE**:

```
  0
BLOCK
  8
0
  2
SAMPLE
 70
     0
 10
0.0
 20
0.0
 30
0.0
  3
SAMPLE
  1

  0
ARC
  5
263
  8
0
 10
0.0
 20
22.4468613708478415
 30
0.0
 40
242.9028467109147016
 50
354.6976825438280798
 51
185.3023174561718918
  0
LINE
  5
264
  8
0
 10
-241.8634560136443099
 20
0.0000000000001137
 30
0.0
 11
241.8634560136443099
 21
-0.0000000000002274
 31
0.0
  0
ENDBLK
  5
262
  8
0
```

Basically, you have an entry which defines the block entities. It will have an **origin** and all the values are relative to the origin for the elements.

If you design it first then you will know what to do.

Once you have the `BLOCK` defined you will be able to use it as an [`INSERT`](https://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acadr14/dxf/insert_al_u05_c.htm).

---

The `BLOCK` itself. The key is the origin. Most are defined with a coordinate of 0,0,0. Then the `ENTITIES` are drawn relative to this origin for a scale of 1:1.

Imagine a rectangle that is 1 unit square for the scale factor of one. Then the coordinates would be:

```
-0.5,  0.5
 0.5,  0.5
 0.5, -0.5
-0.5, -0.5
```

I hope this information helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but that is not what I want to know. How do you calculate the x, y coordinates for the entities from an insert. What does the the scaleX, scaleY values mean ?

Comment: You define a block first at a given size for a native scale of 1. Then you insert it at a given scale. The system handles everything else.

Comment: All the insert needs is the block name, insertion point, scale factors and rotation.

Answer (score 0):

The `BLOCK` entity (otherwise known as a Block Definition) is essentially the 'blueprints' for an `INSERT` (otherwise known as a Block Reference).

Rather than duplicating all of the geometric information constituting the block for every block reference in a drawing, the block definition (`BLOCK` entity) is a 'template' for each block reference, meaning that only the position, rotation & scale of each block reference need be stored.

The Block Definition resides within the Block Symbol Table and is comprised of a `BLOCK` header entity (defining the block name and origin (usually 0,0) among other properties), followed by all geometry forming the block definition, and finally a terminating `ENDBLK` entity.

All geometry contained within the Block Definition is defined relative to the origin of the Block Definition; then, when a Block Reference (`INSERT`) is created, the Block Definition geometry is transformed relative to the insertion point of the Block Reference.